# How to consume different JSON response into a single endpoint for a client in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to consume api json response in the client side. It is for user authentication. When the correct user name and password is given the following response is achieved:
[image]

But when wrong user name or password is given, the following response can be seen.

[image]

For the valid user name and password, I have implemented the following method which works fine for that purpose. But I cannot handle the situation when the wrong user name or password is given.

```
public ResponseEntity<AuthenticateUserOutputModel> getAutheticateUser(
        AuthenticateUserInputModel authenticateUserInput) {

    String url = AUTHENTICATE_USER;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    
    HttpEntity<AuthenticateUserInputModel> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(authenticateUserInput, headers);
    
    MultiValueMap<String, String> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    form.add("username",authenticateUserInput.getUsername() );
    form.add("password", authenticateUserInput.getPassword());
    
    
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(form, headers);
    
     ResponseEntity<AuthenticateUserOutputModel> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
     
     try {
         
         responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestEntity,AuthenticateUserOutputModel.class);
         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        System.out.println("Error Found");
    }finally {
        return responseEntity;
    }
    
}
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to catch this error inside `catch(HttpClientErrorException e)`, inside this catch statement, you can add if with condition `e.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED` to check is this **401 Unauthorized**, then you know that something with your Authorization is wrong (password or username) and inside this if statement you can do something (return particular information for user or thorw an exception)

```
public ResponseEntity<AuthenticateUserOutputModel> getAutheticateUser(
        AuthenticateUserInputModel authenticateUserInput) {

    String url = AUTHENTICATE_USER;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpEntity<AuthenticateUserInputModel> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(authenticateUserInput, headers);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    form.add("username",authenticateUserInput.getUsername() );
    form.add("password", authenticateUserInput.getPassword());


    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(form, headers);

    ResponseEntity<AuthenticateUserOutputModel> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);

    try {

        responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestEntity,AuthenticateUserOutputModel.class);
        
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {

        if (e.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) {
            // Do something when 401
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Error Found");
    }finally {
        return responseEntity;
    }

}
```

Comment: When 401 occurs, it doesnt go to if statement, rather it directly throws an exception.

Comment: I will fixed my answer, maybe this will be work

Comment: Yes, now I am going to the catch block of HttpClientErrorException. But is there anyway to get the json response along with that as per I mentioned in the 2nd pic?

Comment: You can use getResponseBodyAsString() on this exception, but this return many other things, like statusCode, statusText, etc, apart from the reason/message of the Exception. You will have to manually parse it from the exception.